# About where zero row vectors occur in reduced row echelon matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

> Consider reduced row echelon  matrix $$
>       R=  \begin{pmatrix}
>         r_1 \\
>         \ldots \\
>         \ldots \\
>         r_n \\
>         0 \\
>         \ldots
>         \end{pmatrix}
> $$ where $\{r_1, r_2, r_3, \ldots, r_n\}$ are the nonzero dependent row vectors of $R$. Then $r_k = c_1r_1 + c_2r_2 +  \ldots + c_{k-1}r_{k-1}$ where $1 \le k \le n$ and so $r_k - (c_1r_1 + c_2r_2 + \ldots + c_{k-1}r_{k-1}) = 0$ **which means there occurs a zero vector before $r_n$**.

The quote above is a part of a proof. I am stuck at the bolded part. Can someone elaborate how the conclusion in bold follows?

Edit:

Statement:  if $R$ is a reduced row echelon matrix then the nonzero rows of 
$R$ are linearly independent.

Proof: The quote above is a contradiction ($k > n$) to the fact that $0$ vectors occurs after $r_n$.

Comment: Context missing. Normally, in a reduced row echelon matrix, the nonzero rows should be independent, and an $r_k = \cdots$ equation like in your case cannot hold. But hell knows what this particular author means by "reduced row echelon matrix".

Comment: @ darij grinberg, I edited my OP.

Comment: Then I don't see why the conclusion holds. The author seems to have goofed here; read any other text (or fill in the argument yourself: what can you say about the column of the pivot of row $r_i$, where $i$ is the smallest nonzero index satisfying $c_i \neq 0$ ?).

Comment: Just to be sure I am not the one who goofed here I link the proof as is : https://s29.postimg.org/7lgaun8s7/Capture.png If it still makes no sense I'll look elsewhere

Comment: Perhaps what we need to do is take a look at this particular author's defininition of reduced row echelon form.

Comment: Ah! The inclusion of row operations is actually quite interesting, and somewhat of a game-changer. I'm saying "somewhat" because I don't know how he defines a row-echelon form, and depending on the definition it's not clear whether it is required to be unsimplifiable by any row operations.